# C# application deployment with database

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2005, deployment, .net-3.5

I have created a simple application in C#.net 3.5, where i use database to insert, update, view & delete records. Now i want to deploy that application in other computer. How to package it with the sql database, so that when i install the application on other pc, the database should also be deployed into it.

should the other machine have sql & .net framework installed..?

Any Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: sqlce,sqite,sql ex?which ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use "[Sql Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ff687142.aspx)" Edition...you can deploy it easily with your application...it will create an DB file which you can export with your application.

Also you can try [Visual Studio Setup Project](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353). This project can detect automatically wether Sql Compact Client is installed on target machine or not...and if NOT it will install it.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your final release with [spoon stedio](http://spoon.net/studio/features/virtualization),it have a lot of advantage like run .net application with out installing .net frame work and databases such as `SQL Server`

> Spoon is the only virtualization engine in its class to support
>   virtualization of both 32- and 64-bit applications; system services
>   and databases such as SQL Server; and advanced software technologies
>   such as DCOM and SxS.
>
> Run .NET Without .NET
>
> Embed runtime dependencies such as .NET, Java, AIR, and SQL CE
>   directly into virtual applications. Launch on completely clean
>   desktops.

**Edited**
There is an article about:
[Deploy your Application and Database](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16231/Deploy-your-Application-and-Database)

Comment: I want to use Visual Studio's in built deployment & packaging facilty

Comment: you just make your application,for publish you application you can build final release with spoon studio,it will put all application requirement like .net frame work or sql server in exe file

Comment: @Nirav Chheda:you are using sqlce,sqlite or sqlexpress?

Comment: @isrog : see my edit. I am using Microsoft SQL server 2005 / 2008 Enterprise Edition.

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11131168/deploying-a-desktop-application-with-sql-server-express and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16231/Deploy-your-Application-and-Database links